# insert multi value from checkboxs into database by php

Tags: php, database, checkbox, insert

i want insert this form value to datanase :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="brand1" id="brand1" value="1"> <label for="brand1">Brand 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand2" id="brand2" value="1"> <label for="brand2">Brand 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand3" id="brand3" value="1"> <label for="brand3">Brand 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand4" id="brand4" value="1"> <label for="brand4">Brand 4</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand5" id="brand5" value="1"> <label for="brand5">Brand 5</label>
```

these text box are get by php from a table in database and may be Variable

i want insert to database by this format
if brand 1 are checked $brand="1,";

and Finally like this :

```
insert($name,$brands); and $brands = "1,2,3,4,5,";
```

if write this by if and while but it doesn't work because if insert run in while {} Five times insert Done  and if insert run out of while {} , $brand = "5,"

thanks for your help or idea for this problem

it's mean :

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<?php
$result = $db->getall(brands);
        if(!empty($result)) {
    while ( list($key,$val)=each($result) ) {
        $brand_id = stripslashes($val["id"]);
        $brand_name = stripslashes($val["name"]);
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="brand<?php print"$brand_id"; ?>" value="1" style="cursor:pointer;"><label for="brand<?php print"$brand_id"; ?>" style="cursor:pointer;"> <?php print"$brand_name"; ?></label>
    <?php }} ?>
```

Source Output:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="brand1" value="1"> <label for="brand1">Brand Name 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand2" value="1"> <label for="brand2">Brand Name 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand3" value="1"> <label for="brand3">Brand Name 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand4" value="1"> <label for="brand4">Brand Name 4</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand5" value="1"> <label for="brand5">Brand Name 5</label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

when submit form , insert source is :

```
    <?php
$result = $db->getall(brands);
        if(!empty($result)) {
    while ( list($key,$val)=each($result) ) {
        $brand_id = brand.stripslashes($val["id"]);
        $brand_name = stripslashes($val["name"]);
    $brand_ids = "brand.$brand_id";
    if($$brand_ids==1) {$brands="$brandid,"}

}} ?>
$db->add_submenu("$brands");
```

Comment: I think you should try to edit your question and explain everything once again, because it's difficult to understand how do you want to insert and what is your problem.

Comment: `$db->add_submenu("$brands");` is outside of PHP block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the name of your checkboxes to `brand[]`. It will give you an array once submitted at `$_POST['brand']`

```
Ex. 

<input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="1" ... />
<input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="2" ... />
<input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="3" ... />
<input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="4" ... />
<input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="5" ... />
```

on the other side you can either do something like the following:

```
// this will return '1, 2, 3, 4, 5' when all are selected. 
$index = implode(", ", $_POST['brand']);
```

and at that point you will have the brands in comma delimited form.